# .htaccess ignore directory but include subdirectory with the same name

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a directory called 'success-centers'  (i dont want to go here)
I have a subdirectory called 'portal-pages/success-centers'

How do I ignore the first one but have my URL be:
local.com/success-centers/ OR local.com/success-centers/index.html through .htaccess?

this is my current htaccess file in the ROOT.  it works fine but when I go to local.com/success-centers/  it goes to the directory that I do NOT want to go to.

Any help would be great. thanks.

```
RewriteEngine On

# add a trailing slash if portal-pages/$1 is a directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/portal-pages/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(?!portal-pages/)(.*)$ portal-pages/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: `local.com/success-centers/`  goes to Index of /success-centers which is what I do NOT want.

`local.com/success-centers/` needs to go to the index of  `portal-pages/success-centers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# add a trailing slash if portal-pages/$1 is a directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/portal-pages/$1 -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!portal-pages/)(.*)$ portal-pages/$1 [L,NC]
```

There is no need to check for `-f` or `-d` as you want `portal-pages/success-centers/` when URI in browser is `/success-centers/`.

Comment: thanks, its going to the right page now but now but im getting all of these errors:
take a look http://travelingwiththemorgans.com/Success_Centers.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly and you want the browser to point to a different page, but you *don't* want the URL of that different page to show up in the URL bar, you will need something along the lines of:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^success-centers(.*) /portal-pages/success-centers$1 [L]
```